# Refresh jQuery counter Plugin Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I use a jQuery counter which move numbers from one fixed number to other fixed number. But I want to create the Counter which end at number which come from MySQL database and updated every time with a get function.

HTML AND JS Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  function RefreshCounter()
  {
    $.get("includes/counter.php", function(upd)
    {
      $(".counter").attr("data-stop", upd);
      $(".counter").attr("data-format", upd);
    });
    $(".counter").counter();
  }

  RefreshCounter();

  setInterval(function(){RefreshCounter()}, 5000);
});
```

```html
<p id="counter">
   <span class="counter counter-analog" data-direction="up" data-interval="1000" data-format="<?php echo $countCalcul; ?>" data-stop="<?php echo $countCalcul; ?>"><?php echo $countCalcul; ?></span>
</p>


<?php
// PHP Code Working 100%
require("bd.php");
$req = $bdd->query('SELECT SUM(nb_calcul) AS countCalcul FROM visiteurs');
$donnees = $req->fetch();
$countCalcul = $donnees['countCalcul'];
$req->closeCursor();
   
echo $countCalcul;
?>
```

The problem is when the counter Reach the end "data-stop" it's restaring from 0 with the console message:

counter.js:47 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at refresh (counter.js:47)at HTMLSpanElement.tick (counter.js:32) at e (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2)

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: You need to include the html created by <?php echo $countCalcul; ?>

Comment: it's a int variable from php file with mySQL, it's can be from 0 to 99999..